# Insert into no duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

Create Table as follows where id are AI and primary key.

id | game_id | player_id |

I want to enter values that are not duplicates, but I cannot make player_id and game_id the primary key because player_id is constant and in game_id a player with a different game_id can come and have a game_id the same with another player.

E.g

```
id | game_id | player_id | 
1      14           5
2      14           6
3      17           5      
4      5            5
5      10           6
6      5            6
```

I design a table with game_id and id unique but, if a player come with the same game_id as one already inserted it will not be inserted.
I want to introduce players who have the same game_id but different player_id as in the example above. You cannot insert the same game_id and player_id only if game_id or player_id is different

Comment: You understand that a unique key can be formed across multiple columns, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a composite unique key on the player/game tuple:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  game_id int NOT NULL,
  player_id int NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY game_player (game_id,player_id)
);
```

With this set up in place:

```
insert into mytable(game_id, player_id) values(1, 1); 
-- ok
insert into mytable(game_id, player_id) values(1, 2); 
-- ok
insert into mytable(game_id, player_id) values(2, 1); 
-- ok
insert into mytable(game_id, player_id) values(1, 1);
-- Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'game_player'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kAuVnggFyaoT5eppsgG51U/0)**

Comment: Thanks, now i saw that for game_id i need a value greater than 2285231564 which does not enter a simple int

Comment: @RazvanDancea: you can use `bigint`.

Comment: I used varchar(255) to be sure. I have tested it now and it works flawlessly thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome @RavzanDancea! I would still recommend using a numeric datatype instead of a string, which is suboptimal in you use case. Bigint can store values up to 2^63...

Comment: @RazvanDancea . . . You can also use `numeric`, but GMB is right to avoid strings for this.